# TensorRT and Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorrt

I am trying to speed up the inference of yolov3 TF2 with TensorRT.
I am using the TrtGraphConverter function in tensorflow 2.

My code is essentially this:

```html
from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt

tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverter(
    input_saved_model_dir="./tmp/yolosaved/",
    precision_mode="FP16",
    is_dynamic_op=True)
converter.convert()


saved_model_dir_trt = "./tmp/yolov3.trt"
converter.save(saved_model_dir_trt)
```

And this generates the following error:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/Programs/anaconda3/envs/Deep2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 427, in import_graph_def
    graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input 1 of node StatefulPartitionedCall was passed float from conv2d/kernel:0 incompatible with expected resource.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pierre/Documents/GitHub/yolov3-tf2/tensorrt.py", line 23, in <module>
    converter.save(saved_model_dir_trt)
  File "/home/pierre/Programs/anaconda3/envs/Deep2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compiler/tensorrt/trt_convert.py", line 822, in save
    super(TrtGraphConverter, self).save(output_saved_model_dir)
  File "/home/pierre/Programs/anaconda3/envs/Deep2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/compiler/tensorrt/trt_convert.py", line 432, in save
    importer.import_graph_def(self._converted_graph_def, name="")
  File "/home/pierre/Programs/anaconda3/envs/Deep2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pierre/Programs/anaconda3/envs/Deep2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 431, in import_graph_def
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Input 1 of node StatefulPartitionedCall was passed float from conv2d/kernel:0 incompatible with expected resource.
```

Does this mean that some of my nodes can't be converted? In this case, why does my code error out during the .save step?

Comment: I found a GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25348), where you say it works for you with a nightly version of TF. Could you please post as an answer the exact version of a package and additional steps (if any) required to make it work?
It would be very helpful for me as I have the same issue and potentially for others who comes here from Google.

Comment: Try `precision_mode="FP32"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue with the following code. Also I switched from tf 2.0.-beta0 to tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview

```html
params = trt.DEFAULT_TRT_CONVERSION_PARAMS._replace(
    precision_mode='FP16',
    is_dynamic_op=True)
    
converter = trt.TrtGraphConverterV2(
    input_saved_model_dir=saved_model_dir,
    conversion_params=params)
converter.convert()
saved_model_dir_trt = "/tmp/model.trt"
converter.save(saved_model_dir_trt)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks! Could you please update the answer with the version of TensorFlow that you use, because in [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25348) you said you used `2.0.0-beta0` and switching to `tf-nightly-gpu-2.0-preview` helped to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's TensortRT version used?

Comment: what's difference between this converter and your converter? from tensorflow.contrib.tensorrt as trt         trt_graph = trt.create_inference_graph(
    input_graph_def = frozen_graph_def,
    outputs = output_node_name,
    max_batch_size=batch_size,
    max_workspace_size_bytes=workspace_size,
    precision_mode=precision,
    minimum_segment_size=3)

Comment: How much time does it take to complete the conversion?

Answer (score 2):

When you are using TensorRT please keep in mind that there might be unsupported layers in your model architecture. There is [TensorRT support matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-support-matrix/index.html#layers-matrix) for your reference. YOLO consist a lot of unimplemented custom layers such as "yolo layer".

So, if you want to convert YOLO to TensorRT optimized model, you need to choose from alternative ways.

1. Try [TF-TRT](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html) which optimizes and executes compatible subgraphs, allowing TensorFlow to execute the remaining graph. While you can still use TensorFlow's wide and flexible feature set, TensorRT will parse the model and apply optimizations to the portions of the graph wherever possible.
2. Implement your [custom layers](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/tensorrt-developer-guide/index.html#extending) with Plugin API like [this](https://github.com/AastaNV/Face-Recognition) example.

Comment: I don't understand your mean. So, in the two cases, the TF-TRT and TensorRT ways both methods are applied optimization to subgraph, right? If so, What's difference between two methods?

Comment: @DeeeepNet Using TensorRT to convert the whole model means it tries to convert all layers/operations. This means it will fail if the layer/operation is not supported by TensorRT. You can implement a custom layer for those to make it work. Alternatively, using TF-TRT, the optimizer only converts layers that are compatible with TensorRT and uses Tensorflow to run the other layers.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a reach, but which gpu are you using? I know that `precision_mode="FP16"` is just supported in certain architectures, like Pascal (tx2 series) and Turing (~2080 series). I've had good results porting from TF2 to trt with fp16.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I am doing this now with YoloV4 based on Keras. I have managed to convert it to TRT but how do you use the converted model to infer from it? I have used:

```
saved_model_loaded = tf.saved_model.load(input_saved_model, tags=[tag_constants.SERVING])
signature_keys = list(saved_model_loaded.signatures.keys())
print(signature_keys)

infer = saved_model_loaded.signatures['serving_default']
print(infer.structured_outputs)
```

as per NVIDIA's colab but it does not work with infer(X).